# Blacklisted Param/Header Names in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've experienced a behavior where I would specify a header/parameter with a certain name in the request and send it to the Node application (using Postman/BurpSuite), but it doesn't appear in the request body/headers in the application's controller. I suspect it's a NodeJS builtin security feature, but I'm not sure.

Are there blacklisted header/parameter names in NodeJS?

It's confirmed that the framework is not the one to blame.
I can't reveal the name, since the nature of the post.

Comment: what kind of header did you add?

Comment: No funny letters, characters are within the alphabet. Due to nature of the post, I can not revel the name.

Comment: Are your headers like X-Something?

Comment: @Soufiane Tahiri  Nope.

Comment: This could answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions

Comment: @Soufiane Tahiri I don't see how this is related.  May you elaborate.